# How to use appendToDocumentList in webMethods?

Tags: xml, webmethods

This is the main XML structure:

```
<A> 
    <B> 
        <C>letter C</C> 
    </B>
</A>
```

I'd like to insert certain block xml after element B.

Comment: What language are you using to manipulate the XML, Can you provide your non-working example?

Comment: I am using webMethods for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pub.list:appendToDocumentList operates over IData (document). To use it you need to create this document.

Is your XML structure static?
If **yes** create a document on IS that resembles your XML structure, then (assuming you have your XML in a string):

1. convert string to IData (document) using:

   - *pub.xml:xmlStringToXMLNode*
   - *pub.xml:xmlNodeToDocument*
2. Use *pub.list:appendToDocumentList* to add new element to e.g. `<B>` list
3. Convert document back to string using *pub.xml:documentToXMLString*

If **no** you still need to create a document in the pipeline:
[image]

and then use *pub.list:appendToDocumentList*:
[image]

Ultimetly if required, convert document to string using *pub.xml:documentToXMLString*